# Ionic app not opening in iphone 7 plus showing white screen,But its working in iphone 6?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

My ionic app not opening up in iphone 7 plus..

[Showing blank empty screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ttcj.jpg)

But its opening in iphone 6..

[Showing the app login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEXC4.png)

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Sounds like you need to research "white screen of death" issues.  That is often an exception at startup due to missing JS/Plugin resources, exceptions, or using a plugin before `platform.ready`.  Could it be a timing issue where one device happens to load things faster?

Comment: did you try to debug it  in xcode ? i am sure you will find anything more useful to help you debug

Comment: I would also check your plugins using "cordova plugins -ls" and you can check to see if any need updates via "npm outdated". It sounds like ionic-webview may have something to do with it, but there's not enough information given to know.

Comment: yes facing the same issue.